# Merge rows from one pair of columns into another

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here's a link to an example of what I want to achieve: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Append-Rows-using-Another-columns/m-p/401836. Basically, I need to merge all the rows of a pair of columns into another pair of columns. How can I do this in Spark Scala?

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand that you have a dataframe with 4 columns and you want two of them to be in the previous couple of columns right?

For instance with this input (only two rows for simplicity)

```
df.show
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|name|     date1|      cost1|     date2|    cost2|
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|   A|2013-03-25|19923245.06|          |         |
|   B|2015-06-04| 4104660.00|2017-10-16|392073.48|
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

With just a couple of selects and a unionn you can achieve what you want

```
df.select("name", "date1", "cost1")
  .union(df.select("name", "date2", "cost2"))
  .withColumnRenamed("date1", "date")
  .withColumnRenamed("cost1", "cost")

+----+----------+-----------+
|name|      date|       cost|
+----+----------+-----------+
|   A|2013-03-25|19923245.06|
|   B|2015-06-04| 4104660.00|
|   A|          |           |
|   B|2017-10-16|  392073.48|
+----+----------+-----------+
```